# Filter a List via Another

Tags: c#, linq

I have a requirement to filter a list of Clients based on if they haven't had any jobs booked in the last x months.  In my code I have two lists, one is my Clients and the other is a filtered List of Jobs between today and x months ago and the idea is to filter Clients based on their id not appearing in the jobs list.  I tried the following:

```
filteredClients.Where(n => jobsToSearch.Count(j => j.Client == n.ClientID) == 0).ToList();
```

But I seem to get ALL clients regardless. I can easily do a foreach but this severly slows down the process.  How can I filter the client list based on the job list effectively?

Comment: are j.Client and n.ClientID integers?

Comment: Are you sure that the `jobsToSearch` query is correct? Your code looks like it should to do what you intend it to do. If it doesn't optimizations won't help you either.

Comment: You never assign the results to anything. `.Where()` returns a new sequence. It does not modify the existing sequence in place.

Comment: To clarify, yes they are integers and I do assign it to itself I accidentally omitted that above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing you're doing wrong is that you don't assign your results back to something. That's why your original seemed to keep all clients. But we can still improve on the original:

```
filteredClients = filteredClients.Where(n => !jobsToSearch.Any(j => j.Client == n.ClientId)).ToList();
```

The difference between this and your `.Count()` solution is that `.Any()` can stop looking at the jobs list with each client as soon as it encounters the first match, so it should run a bit faster. But we're not done yet. We can do even better by narrowing the jobs list down to only distinct clients:

```
var badClients = jobsToSearch.Select(j => j.Client).Distinct().ToList();
filteredClients = filteredClients.Where(n => !badClients.Any(j => j == n.ClientId)).ToList();
```

And likely even better still by using a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), which can make O(1) lookups like a Dcitionary. Assuming the client ID is an int:

```
 var badClients = new HashSet<int>(jobsToSearch.Select(j => j.Client));
 filteredClients = filteredClients.Where(n => !badClients.Contains(n.ClientId)).ToList();
```

Whether this last option performs better depends on the number of clients that have jobs... if the list is short, the .Distinct() might still do better.

Finally, I don't normally recommend calling `.ToList()` like this. As much as possible, save actually realizing a List, Array, or collection type until the last possible moment, and just keep it to an Enumerable for as long as possible.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with any kind of ordering. Ideally, `badClients` would just be turned into some sort of `O(1)` lookup (either through `ToLookup`, `ToDictionary`, or just instantiating a `HashSet`). Otherwise `!badClients.Any(j => j == n.ClientId)` can be `O(n)` for each client ID to test.

Comment: Definitely a hashset, since there is not data: the mere existence of the key is enough.

Comment: In fact, I like that enough I'm gonna use it in the answer :)

Comment: I do assign it to itself, I accidentally omitted that from the start of the line.  Tried with first suggestion, still get all clients, second suggestion says the HashSet declaration has invalid arguments.

Comment: @user1166905 that sounds like your jobs list is empty.

Comment: Thanks for that, wasn't empty but you prompted me to re-examine the job list and was only returning a fraction of what it should be so the client list was being filtered but to such a small scale I couldn't tell.  Altered and now working with first option you mentioned, just now testing if its quicker than my original code.

Comment: That sounds like your lists are big enough you should really consider the last option.

Answer (score 1):

did you thought about using "groupby"?

without checking the syntax and writing code out of my mind (havnt vs available atm):

```
var groupedJobs = jobsearch.GroupBy(job => job.Client);
var itemsWithJobs = filteredList.Where(item => groupedJobs.ContainsKey(item.ClientID));
```

I can check the syntax tomorrow morning.

The biggest pro of this is, that you have build an Dictonary which is much much faster to search in it. Than to iterate though lists.

Comment: +1 it's this, but instead of `GroupBy` use `ToLookup` and instead of `ContainsKey` just `Contains` (EDIT: If the number of jobs with duplicate ClientIDs are particularly large, then you can use `var groupedJobs = new HashSet<int>(jobsToSearch.Select(j => j.Client))` just to avoid building the grouped collections which aren't really used anyway as all we really need is a ClientID lookup)

Comment: The idea was not to loose the information what jobs where done by client. I think when he needs to know if there where any job done, the next requirment will be to show a list of jobs or at least the count. But it was not asked... so HashSet would have been the better answer... you are right =)

Comment: To clarify, the idea is to filter the list of Clients based on if they had any jobs within a period, I don't need to keep the list of jobs at the end I simply need a filtered list of clients

Comment: So you should use the HashSet ;)

Answer (score 0):

To filter the clients who are `in` IdList;

```
List1.Where(x=> IdList.Contains(x.ClientId));
```

To filter the clients who are `not in` IdList;

```
List1.Where(x=> !IdList.Contains(x.ClientId));
```